# Prove that if $f$ is bilinear, then $\lim_{(h,k) \to 0} \frac{||f(h,k)||}{||(h,k)||}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $f:\Bbb R^n \times\Bbb R^m \to\Bbb R^p$ a bilinear map, prove that $\lim_{(h,k) \to 0} \frac{||f(h,k)||}{||(h,k)||}=0$

How can I prove this? I've tried to use the bilinearity of $f$, expressing it as:
$$f(h,k)=\sum_{i=1}^n {\sum_{j=1}^m} x_i y_j f(e_i,e_j)$$ 
Then I don't know how to proceed ( I suppose I need to find a bound for $||f(h,k)||$, but I might be missing some important theorem because I can't find it).

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, you can write $h=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i$ in coordinates, and $k=\sum_{j=1}^my_jE_j$. Then, observe first that $$\|(h,k)\|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+\sum_{j=1}^my_j^2\right)^{1/2}\geq|x_i|$$ for all $i=1,\dots n$, therefore $$\frac{\|f(h,k)\|}{\|(h,k)\|}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{|x_i||y_j|}{\|(h,k)\|}\|f(e_i,E_j)\|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m|y_j|\|f(e_i,E_j)\|.$$ Since $y_j\to 0$ for all $j$, this shows that the limit you want is equal to $0$.

Comment: You used linear independence at the end right?

Comment: At which step? The first inequality follows from the triangle inequality, the second follows from $\|(h,k)\|\geq |x_i|$, which implies that $\frac{|x_i|}{\|(h,k)\|}\leq 1$.

Comment: $y_j \to 0$ for al $j$

Comment: This follows from $|y_j|\leq \|k\|$, since $\|k\|\to 0$.

Comment: @detnvvp This might be necroposting, but why is it not ok to just say that $h, k = tx, ty$ and let $t \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @Astrum Because then you are not looking at the limit as $h,k\to 0$. You are restricting the variables on lines, which do not capture the full limit.